# How do I set the size of an HTML text box?

Tags: css

How do I set the size of an HTML text box?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Just use:

```
textarea {
    width: 200px;
}
```

or

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Depending on what you mean by 'textbox'.

Comment: note: doing just `input` will also resize other `input` controls like buttons

Comment: A textbox is `<input type="textbox" />` and a textarea is `<textarea></textarea>` there is a difference.

Comment: How do you do it in %?

Comment: @MichaelGarrison You mean `type="text"`? Can't find `type="textbox"` defined anywhere: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute

Comment: Yes, `type="text"` is what I meant, I think I just wrote that in a hurry

Answer (score 42):

Your markup:

```
<input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" />
```

The CSS:

```
.resizedTextbox {width: 100px; height: 20px}
```

Keep in mind that text box size is a "victim" of the [W3C box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). What I mean by victim is that the height and width of a text box is the sum of the height/width properties assigned above, in addition to the padding height/width, and the border width. For this reason, your text boxes will be slightly different sizes in different browsers depending on the default padding in different browsers. Although different browsers tend to define different padding to text boxes, most [reset style sheets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) don't tend to include `<input />` tags in their reset sheets, so this is something to keep in mind.

You can standardize this by defining your own padding. Here is your CSS with specified padding, so the text box looks the same in all browsers:

```
.resizedTextbox {width: 100px; height: 20px; padding: 1px}
```

I added 1 pixel padding because some browsers tend to make the text box look too crammed if the padding is 0px. Depending on your design, you may want to add even more padding, but it is highly recommend you define the padding yourself, otherwise you'll be leaving it up to different browsers to decide for themselves. For even more consistency across browsers, you should also define the border yourself.

Answer (score 12):

```
input[type="text"]
{
    width:200px
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your textbox code:

```
<input type="text" class="textboxclass" />
```

Your CSS code:

```
input[type="text"] {
height: 10px;
width: 80px;
}
```

or

```
.textboxclass {
height: 10px;
width: 80px;
}
```

So, first you select your element with attributes (look at first example) or classes(look last example). Later, you assign height and width values to your element.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have already edited this. I will try to ask better questions.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me in IE 10 and FF 23

```
<input type="text" size="100" />
```

Comment: No this will not work a lot of the time  e.g.  current Chrome aka most popular browser circa 2015

Comment: FYI anyone reading this in the future, works fine in Chrome 58 circa mid-2017.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the class method you can use parent-child method to make changes in the text box.

For eg. I've made a form in my form div.

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="form">
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" >Describe your project in detail.</textarea>
</div>
```

Now CSS code will be like:

```css
.form textarea {
    height: 220px;
    width: 342px;
}
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Lookout! The width attribute is clipped by the max-width attribute.
So I used....

```
    <form method="post" style="width:1200px">
    <h4 style="width:1200px">URI <input type="text" name="srcURI" id="srcURI" value="@m.SrcURI" style="width:600px;max-width:600px"/></h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the dependent input width versus container width.

```
.container {
   width: 360px;
}

.container input {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements can be sized with the [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) and [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
input[type="text"]{
padding:10px 0;}
```

This is way it remains independent of what textsize has been set for the textbox. You are increasing the height using padding instead