# How can the size of an input text box be defined in HTML?

Tags: html, css, input

Here is an HTML input text box:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" />
```

What are the options to define the size of the box?

How can this be implemented in CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the size of an HTML text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125509/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-an-html-text-box)

Comment: In some cases just setting `max-width` is sufficient

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You could set its `width`:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 300px;" />
```

or even better define a class:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" class="mytext" />
```

and in a separate CSS file apply the necessary styling:

```
.mytext {
    width: 300px;
}
```

If you want to limit the number of characters that the user can type into this textbox you could use the `maxlength` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" class="mytext" maxlength="25" />
```

Comment: also: you can change the width in terms of "em" (and not "px") and then the size is proportional to the font-size of the text box

Answer (score 49):

The `size` attribute works, as well

```html
<input size="25" type="text">
```

Comment: In what units is this size attribute measured normally?

Comment: If the input is type "text" or "password" then the size refers to the number of characters. You can control the width of the input that way. See [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/size)

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:18pt;height:420px;width:200px;">
```

Or else

```
 <input type="text" id="txtbox">
```

with the css:

```
 #txtbox
    {
     font-size:18pt;
     height:420px;
     width:200px;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new and you should specify units  (px, pt, % v, etc) in css

Comment: Well- The font-size (style="font-size:18pt") was the one I was looking for and that also increases the size of the box. Though not explicitly asked by the OP, it also adds value.

Comment: This worked. Hence thanks a lot. However the text seems to center itself vertically. Can I prevent this in any way?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu Sorry for delay.. Try increasing the width size.. hope you already found answer..

Answer (score 3):

You can set the width in pixels via inline styling:

```html
<input type="text" name="text" style="width: 195px;">
```

You can also set the width with a visible character length:

```html
<input type="text" name="text" size="35">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input size="45" type="text" name="name">
```

The "size" specifies the visible width in characters of the element input.

You can also use the height and width from css.

```
<input type="text" name="name" style="height:100px; width:300px;">
```