# How to increase overall Primefaces size components

Tags: java, primefaces, size, components

I'd like to increase the size of inputTextFields and outputLabels/outputTexts but I'm not able to.

I have tried using the "display: block" trick for labels, but it won't work.

Is there any trick to increase the overall size of every components?

Comment: EVERY component? No... sorry... and 'THE `display:block` trick? No idea... use css learn about specificity

Comment: By "increase the size" do you mean font-size, or width, or height, or...?

Comment: I mean the overall size, like font size, width, height etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545302/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-input-text-box