# Ionic: is there any way to enlarge the text input field?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, richtextbox

I'm trying to create an input field for a writing a paragraph / richtext: so I'm needing to find a way to enlarge the input item to become similar as a richtextbox.

I didn't find how to do so.

So is there anyone who has any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125509/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-an-html-text-box

Comment: @Gene Thanks a lot for the link. changing the `<input>` to a `<textarea>` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `<input>` to a `<textarea>` with custom rows and columns solved my problem.